# How does the nested run loop?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, nsrunloop

How does the nested run loop? It turns each run loop runs the Independence of each other? or they are in sequence? I understand how CFRunLoopStop - stops the last nesting runloop?

Comment: my example https://github.com/mefilt/RunLoop

Comment: You should post the code you are asking about here.  That said, it's unclear to me what is nested about anything in the code.  It looks like you call for the currentRunLoop singleton everywhere.